# An easy way to secure passwords in database

Tags: python, database, security, hash, passwords

I am creating a simple project in flask, this is a simple web where you can sign up and log in. Each time a user signs up, I save their username and password in the database. When someone tries to log in, I compare the data they entered with the data that I have in the database. 
 Now, the thing is that I want to add an element of security to the project, so I want a simple way to secure the passwords that I save in the database. I thought of saving `hash(password)` instead of `password` in the database, and compare the hashed password that the user entered when trying to log in with what I have in the database. The problem with this is that `hash` returns different values every time, so this solution didn't work. Can anyone suggest how can I solve this problem, or suggest a simple algorithm to secure my passwords?

Comment: Use BCrypt. It will do everything for you.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/

Comment: Rule number 1 of security: never roll your own. Use pre-built tools that are known to be secure. Any individual human will likely miss something otherwise.

Comment: hash can't return different values for the same password

Answer (score 1):

Out of easy and secure, you can only choose one (well, there is a tradeoff).

Security level -1: store passwords. It is simple, but a leaked database will let attackers to impersonate users, and will expose users' accounts on other platforms since (sadly) too many people reuse passwords.

Security level 0: store hashes (md5, sha1 etc). A leaked database now won't expose all passwords at once, simple passwords still can be recovered using a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attack, or a  brute-force search.

Security level 1: salted hashes. For each user, generate a random string (salt), which will be stored plain-text. Then, concatenate it with the password and store the resulting hash. With a sufficiently long salt, it will protect from rainbow tables attack or a naive brute-force. It won't stand against dictionary brute-force. This is what `django` and `bcrypt` do.

To deal with dictionary brute-force, enforce password complexity. Unfortunately, it is not a user-friendly solution.

Levels 2 and beyond:

- use external auth provider, e.g. login with Google accounts.
- 2FA (two-factor authentication, like RSA tokens, text messages etc)
- asymmetric cryptography, like one in SSH (e.g., smart card-based)